# Пересоздание ViewModel при повороте экрана

Tags: java, android, android-arch

Недавно `Google` выпустили `Android Architecture Components`, в первой же строке описания сказано:

> The ViewModel class is designed to store and manage UI-related data in
>   a lifecycle conscious way. The ViewModel class allows data to survive
>   configuration changes such as screen rotations.

Вот пример моей  `ViewModel`

**MyViewModel.java**

```
public class MyViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private MutableLiveData<Boolean> refreshStatus = new MutableLiveData<>();

    private MutableLiveData<ResponseHolder<List<MusicSong>>> response = new MutableLiveData<>();

    public MyViewModel() {
        Log.wtf(TAG, "MyViewModel() called = [" + hashCode() + "]");

        //set default value
        response.setValue(ResponseHolder.success(new ArrayList<>()));
    }
}
```

После это получаю экзепмляр `MyViewModel` в `Activity`, а так же в `Fragment` который находится в этой `Activity`.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MyViewModel.class);
}
```

При запуске я вижу как конструктор MyViewModel вызывается два раза, перый из `Activity` и второй из `Fragment`, вот логи:

```
MyViewModel() called with: hashCode = [79759198]

MyViewModel() called with: hashCode = [97210601]
```

И после поворота

```
MyViewModel() called with: hashCode = [60773597]

MyViewModel() called with: hashCode = [186413841]
```

**Вопрос:** так и должно быть что для каждой `Activity` создается новый экземпляр `VideModel` и если да, то как он тогда переживает поворот экрана,  или я что то делаю не так, тогда что?